# What is the purpose of this script posted as an answer?

Tags: discussion

There was a recent post asking about [salvage of pineapple marinated tuna](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/123866/salvage-tuna-marinated-in-pineapple), which had a perfectly fine answer from FuzzyChef. However, a [subsequent answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/123866/salvage-tuna-marinated-in-pineapple/123894#123894) (deleted a few minutes later) from a user with 1 reputation seems to be a some code for a Java program doing something with remote hosts and certificates, which I've reproduced partially here:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
 import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
 import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
 import javax.security.cert.X509Certificate;
 
 
 public class TLSV1_2SocketClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String remoteHost = "10.15.107.21";
    //String remoteHost = "www.google.com";
    int rport = 8445;
    //int rport = 443;
    
    /*
     * System.out.println("Enter Remote host.............."); Scanner input = new
     * Scanner(System.in); String remoteHost = input.nextLine(); // input.close();
     * 
     * System.out.println("Enter Remote port.............."); Scanner input1 = new
     * Scanner(System.in); String remotePort = input1.nextLine(); //input1.close();
     * int rport = Integer.valueOf(remotePort);
     */
    try {
```

It could be a post attempting to ask something in another Stack, but I would have thought that the first thing someone would do there is to get the question down rather than the code (at least that's how my mind works). I guess there's potential for it to be an attempt at something malicious or possibly an accidental copy/paste (though how you might copy/paste, format it and post accidentally is beyond me).

Is this sort of thing something we should be concerned about?

Answer (score 4):

Unless its a common thing its generally not a problem. Some people... are strange and occasionally try to use SE as a pastebin, get confused cause they get too many windows open or (the one thing to be concerned with) try to post *questions* on the wrong site. It might also be an attempt to use the site as a way to check the formatting on a post and... they accidentally posted it. I've seen selfies too.

Unless a user *repeatedly* does this or a site has this as a common problem, its my opinion that its nothing to really worry about.

Comment: The amount of times I've posted something in the wrong chat... My first thought is something simply posted something in the wrong box by accident.

Comment: Once upon a time, my cat posted an immensely personal diary entry I was writing to the IMDb politics chat room.

Comment: If it was your cat, it was probably intentional

Comment: Also, reading the code, there's no way to turn that into an XSS exploit.